# Can't set SSH in AWS EB CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

When I try to set up SSH keys on Elastic Beanstalk CLI, I got this error instead:

```
ERROR: SSH is not installed. You must install SSH before continuing.
```

I don't usually get this error before. Maybe before, the SSH got installed automatically when I install other things, but I somehow missed it now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally can solve it by installing SSH using OpenSSH binary version for Windows from here:

http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html

Comment: https://chocolatey.org/packages/openssh works well.  choco install openssh

Comment: To use this command, SSH must be installed on your local machine and available from the command line. Private key files must be located in a folder named .ssh under your user directory, and the EC2 instances in your environment must have public IP addresses.