# ERROR: CommandError - SSH is not installed. You must install SSH before continuing on ebcli

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I'm setting up a new application. However whenever I try to set up SSH with my instances on ebcli, it results in the error bellow.

I have already reinstalled the open ssh client and I am able to generate keys in the terminal as well. I am not exactly sure what to do next

Here is the error:

> Type a keypair name. (Default is aws-eb): ERROR: CommandError - SSH is
>   not installed. You must install SSH before continuing.

Comment: Which eb command are you running when this error takes place? If it's `eb init` are there any other arguments you've used when running that command?

Comment: @ChaseAllbee it is during the eb init , when i am first trying to set up a new application using beanstalk. It is during the phase where they ask to set up a key pair for the ec2 instance.

Comment: I see. It appears some other folks have had a [similar error here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459005/cant-set-ssh-in-aws-eb-cli). You have already reinstalled open-ssh so could you perform the following steps: 

1) Check you have private key files in your ~/.ssh/ folder

2) Run `which ssh` to ensure your ssh client is what you think it is